# how to add new threads to a Threadpoolexecutor with a button in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, python-multithreading, kivy-language, kivymd

i need to add a new thread while other is already running by using a button in kivy
by using ThreadPoolExecutor

'''
class Loginscreen(Screen):
def **init**(self, **kw):
super().**init**(**kw)

```
def calling(self, *args):
    self.func()

def imprimir(self, *args):
    self.palabra1 = self.ids.emaillogin.text
    self.palabra2 = self.ids.passwordlogin.text

def func(self, *args):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.imprimir, 0)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(self.palabra1, self.palabra2)

def call(self, *args):
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.imprimir, 1 / 1)

pass
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Loginscreen(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(Request(name='request'))


class work(MDApp):
    def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Yellow"
    screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
    return screen


work().run()
```

'''

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.